# is there any algorithm for finding the target genes of some motifs based on the motifs sequences?

Tags: python, r, bioinformatics, genetic-algorithm, genetics

I have an issue and till now I could not find any directions regarding that.
I have the position of my ChIP-Seq peaks in the BED format (fig2) and I found some motifs related to them by HOMER. As you know homer gives the motif's names and sequences only(fig1). But now based on the motifs and also sequence of my peaks list(examples 'df' dataframe) that already i have, I would like to find-out which peaks contains those motifs and later on by finding the overlap between peaks that contain motif seq and gene names list (fig3), get final target genes.

to make the statement easier I added some pictures and mentioned some explanations as well:
[image: motif sequence]
[image: peak positions][image: peaks discription and gene names]

First by peak positions I got motif sequence then by this motif sequence i want to underestand which one of my peaks in peak list have that motif. (I got many motifs and i have big peak positions list) by overlaping peak positions with peak discription list.

- challenge is, in motif sequences I have many not conserved nucleotides but I have a core conserved sequence like (CAAGG) so, I'm searching for algorithms or some functions that I can align the motif sequence with peak sequence list (like that df dataframe), to see which peaks have that motif sequence but because of those not conserved sequences I would like to define that if i have some not conserved nucleotides consider available possibilities based on the motif sequence like in the picture in first position consider [C/T/G] and in the second only [T/C] not all bases possibilities for not consereved nucleotides.

Of course after these steps still I have some genes as a false positive and I can not say all those genes have by 100% sure that motif sequences but at least I have less genes posibilities to investigate them compare to 15K gene names at the begining.

- example of peak sequences list:

```
df <-data.frame(
  position=c( "chr1,1165251,1165500","chr1,2147751,2148000"),
  SEQ=c("CAGCACCAGGAACAGTGCGGCCGTGAGCTCAGCCTTCAAGGTCAAGCTCCTCACCTCCCTGTCAGAGCCCTGGCTCCAGCGT",
        "AAGAGGGGAAAAGACCATAGCAGAGAGCTCAGCCTGAGCTCCTCACCTCCCTGTCAGAGCCACGG")
```

out put would be something like below. Infact I need to find the targets of that motif sequence in "df" file, then I will find which gene has that target by comparing the location of the peaks (output) with excel file that I have and contains the names and also positions of my original file (fig.3).

```
output<-data.frame(
  position=( "chr1,1165251,1165500")
```

I hope I explained well everything.

Thank in advance for any help.

Comment: Include the output you want to get

Comment: @ onyambu      Sorry for delay. I edited my question and I added the exmaple of output file as well.  Maybe it is better to mention, nucleotide substitutions that are allowed to use must be according to nucleotide IUPAC letters.